# Problem installing last build of Sniffles

Tags: software-installation

I have followed the steps described [here](https://github.com/fritzsedlazeck/Sniffles/wiki#how-to-build-sniffles) to install Sniffles on my Mac Book Pro running macOS High Sierra.

However, I am struggling with this step:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.7 -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.7 ..
```

I do not have an /opt folder, so I get the following output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    /opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.7

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.7

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/xxx/Documents/xxx/xxx/Sniffles-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/xxx/Documents/xxx/xxx/Sniffles-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Unsurprisingly, the error file says that /opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.7 does not exist.

So I tried:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc ..
```

I get another long message but the most important bit is:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS)
```

I do not know what to do to solve this error.

I do have gcc here: /usr/bin/gcc and cmake version 3.8.1.

I have created an issue on the [Sniffles GitHub repository](https://github.com/fritzsedlazeck/Sniffles/issues/80).

#### Update 13th June 2018

I installed the latest version of gcc:

```
brew install gcc
Warning: gcc 8.1.0 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 8.1.0, run `brew reinstall gcc`
```

Then, I tried to make cmake use gcc and g++ in the /usr/local/bin folder.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/gcc-8 -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/g++-8 ..
```

This recreated the same problem:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS)
```

Do I need to set the OpenMP_C*_FLAGS to something?

Comment: Do you have OpenMP installed? It's required.

Comment: @DevonRyan OpenMP is installed as part of GCC. The problem is that OP isn’t using GCC.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install GCC, or a newer version of Clang.

Your compiler — though the binary is called `gcc` — is actually Clang, and the Clang version that’s shipping with macOS/Xcode still does not support OpenMP.

The easiest course of action is probably to install GCC via Homebrew (`brew install gcc`) and then configure Sniffles to use Homebrew’s GCC (i.e. setting the `CMAKE_C*_COMPILER` paths to `/usr/local/bin/g{cc,++}-$version`).

Comment: I have tried what you said, unsuccessfully. I have updated my original question.